# How to connect to localhost with DSL IP forward

Tags: networking, dsl, modem

I'm trying to connect to wamp from other computer.

I have a tp-link TD-8811. Is there any way to open my localhost from out

also i dont have a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the specs for your TP-link device show that it is capable of DMZ and Virtual Server configurations.  Please see here for a Step-by-Step: http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?faqid=205  I input your model number in the search and came up with this article.  I hope this helps.

---

There are many options for accessing a dynamic IP from outside.

Almost all services that do CNAME aliases for dynamic IPs offer both free and paid services.  I never felt the need to pay for a service that i only used occasionally...  The paid packages are usually geared to make your life easier.

Look at: no-ip.com -or- dyndns.com -or- google: "connect to dynamic ip address" and take your pick from the results.

---

After all of this is done, I'd seriously consider setting up (as an absolute minimum) a quick and dirty encrypted channel for your security.  Your Router does not support IPsec/VPN, but that doesn't mean that you cannot ssh to your computer (regardless of host/client OS).  There are also port-knocking methods to "speak" to your PC's firewall and instruct it to open your desired data port.  You'll need to forward a few more ports from your router to get this set up, but if you'll achieve a closed system that you can open and close again on demand.

Apologies for the non-howto style of this answer, I hope it helps.